# moving raid 5 hard disks from ibm x3500 m1 to ibm x3650 m1

Tags: disaster-recovery, ibm-xseries

one of our server ibm x3500 m1 type 7977 dead yesterday. can we move its hard drive to access data on raid 5 logical drive on ibm x3650 m1 server with same serveRaid 8K raid controller?

Usman

Comment: If it's the same controller, same firmware, same everything: yes, should be OK. Keep the disk order, the "new" controller should accept the RAID5 as foreign but optimal (maybe after verification). Note: this is in no way a guarantee, as these controllers are quite old and I can't verify it.

Comment: and if i install same controller card from old server to new one? do i need to worry about firmware in this case?

Comment: Yeah, that would work. No need to worry about firmware.